# SyntaxError: Illegal return statement Postgres Typescript/Nextjs

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js

I tried to insert using https://node-postgres.com/

For select / get data it was successfully returned the data but when I tried to insert using query I got an error

client.ts

```
import { Client  } from 'pg'

const client = new Client ({
  connectionString: "MY_DATABASE_URL",
  ssl: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

export default client
```

submit handler

```
const submit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void }) => {
    e.preventDefault()
  
      const query = `
      INSERT INTO mesin
          (nama_mesin, nomer_mesin, kategori, status_mesin)
      VALUES
          ('test2', 'test2', 'test2', 'test2')
      `

      try {
        const res = await client.query(query)
        console.log(res.rows[0])
      
      } catch (err:any) {
        console.log(err.stack)
      }
  }
```

error

```
- error SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
    at __webpack_require__ (user\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (user\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (user\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (user\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./db/client.ts:5:60)
    at Module.(sc_client)/./db/client.ts (user\.next\server\app\mesin\page.js:663:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (user\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (./app/mesin/page.tsx:16:68)
    at Module.(sc_client)/./app/mesin/page.tsx (user\.next\server\app\mesin\page.js:553:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (user\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
```

Comment: `catch (err:any)` does not look like valid TypeScript to me